# What is the equivalent of SQL's WITHIN GROUP in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert a stored procedure which is written in T-SQL to BigQuery compatible syntax.

In one of the temp table used inside the proc, there is a function `WITHIN GROUP` as given in the query below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    flr_id, lid, sentinel, liquid, d_id, sent_time, tracker, 
    (PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ((DATE_DIFF(second, (sent_time), (tracker))/3600.0)) ASC) OVER (PARTITION BY flr_id, sentinel, d_id)/24.0) AS mct 
FROM 
    history AS h 
INNER JOIN 
    magent AS mag ON mag.flat = h.flat 
INNER JOIN 
    stepand AS stepand ON stepand.soid = h.soid 
INNER JOIN 
    sv AS st_v ON st_v.stoid = stepand.stoid 
INNER JOIN 
    tvr AS tvr ON tvr.trvid = stepand.trvid 
INNER JOIN 
    sdv AS sdv ON st_v.stoid = sdv.stoid 
WHERE 
    liquid > 0 
    AND mag.flr_id = '1234' 
    AND tracker <= GETDATE() 
    AND sent_time >= DATEADD(WEEK, 1, GETDATE()) 
    AND d_id NOT LIKE ('UNKNOWN') 
    AND part_type_code NOT IN ('ABCDE') 
    AND h.lid not like 'B%' 
    AND h.lid not like 'T%' 
    AND h.lid not like 'VL%' 
    AND h.step_deleted_sw <> 'Y' 
    AND h.lid NOT IN (SELECT lid from test)");
```

I converted all of the query except for this line.

> (PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ((DATE_DIFF(second,
> (sent_time), (tracker))/3600.0)) ASC) OVER (PARTITION BY flr_id,
> sentinel, d_id)/24.0) AS mct

I looked for WITHIN GROUP in SQL and found a good explanation [here](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/the-within-group-and-filter-sql-clauses-of-postgresql-9-4/)

What I don't understand is what is the equivalent function for `WITHIN GROUP` on Bigquery ?
When I tried to run the query as it is, I get an error

```
Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword WITHIN at <PROCNAME>
```

Could anyone let me know how can I modify the line using `WITHIN GROUP` to big query compatible syntax ?
Ant help is much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you provided sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want to do, BigQuery implements this using the `ORDER BY` for the window function:

```
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) OVER (PARTITION BY flr_id, sentinel, d_id)/24.0
                           ORDER BY ((DATE_DIFF(second, (sent_time), (tracker))/3600.0)) ASC
                          ) AS mct
```

Of course the `DATE_DIFF()` syntax is not correct for BigQuery and your query may have other issues as well.  However, this answers the question that you specifically asked.

Comment: I used TIMESTAMP_DIFF for the same (DATE_DIFF doesn't give SECONDS) and made syntactical changes as per Bigquery. The one I dont understand is the `WITHIN GROUP` part.